# Can I use BootCamp on an existing Windows partition?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I have a Windows 7 PC which is getting old and flaky. I am switching to a Mac Mini as my primary desktop (since I also do Mac development) but will use it mainly for Windows.

What I'd really love to do is clone my W7 partition onto a new SSD and then use this on the Mac Mini, so I can carry on using my "old PC" without having to reinstall everything. I know I could do that cloning process if I was keeping the same PC but replacing the disk with SSD.**

Does BootCamp allow you to "wrap"/load an existing partition or do you have to create a new clean partition and then install an OS?

***I'm aware that Windows doesn't like fidning the PC spec has suddenly totally changed but that's a separate issue really, I'd rather not distract the main question here*

Comment: If it's an option to load my W7 partition inside Parallels instead more easily, I'm open to that too, it's a tangent to the main question but I'm happy to hear if it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is a whole bunch of links so I'm not really sure it qualifies as an answer...

Windows -> Parallels - possible with the Parallels Transporter Agent software - http://kb.parallels.com/uk/115007

Parallels -> Bootcamp - http://www.tylercrumpton.com/?p=90

Windows straight to Bootcamp [needs WinClone, not free] - http://twocanoes.com/winclone/support/migrating-a-real-pc-to-boot-camp-with-winclone-4